# Calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas (días vencidos) en C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Estaba haciendo este código en donde guarda las características de un producto incluido la fecha de vencimiento (incluido si el producto vence o no), ahora quisiera que calculara los días de vencimiento pero no se cómo hacerlo, ¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct fecha{
    int d,m,a;
};
struct tienda{
  char nombreitem[20];
  int  precio;
  int cantidad;
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int year;
  fecha vc;
}c1[100];

int vence(fecha vc,fecha hoy) {
    int e=0;
    e=hoy.a-vc.a;
    if(vc.m==hoy.m && vc.d>hoy.d)e--;
    else if(vc.m>hoy.m)e--;
    return e;
};
int main(){
fecha hoy;
hoy.d=27; hoy.m=8; hoy.a=2018;
int cant_productos,e=0,df;
    cout<<"cantidad de productos: ";
    cin>>cant_productos;

    for(int i=0;i<cant_productos;i++){

    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre item:        ";
    cin.getline(c1[i].nombreitem,20,'\n');
    cout<<"precio:             ";
    cin>>c1[i].precio;
    cout<<"cantidad:           ";
    cin>>c1[i].cantidad;



    cout<<"dia de vencimiento: ";
    cin>>c1[i].dia;
    if(c1[i].dia>31){
    cout<<"intente nuevamente";
    return 0;
    }


    cout<<"mes de vencimiento: ";
    cin>>c1[i].mes;
    if(c1[i].mes>12){
    cout<<"intente nuevamente";
    return 0;
    }


    cout<<"año de vencimiento: ";
    cin>>c1[i].year;
    if(c1[i].year<2999){
    cout<<"intente nuevamente";
    return 0;
    }


    cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"\n :Lista de productos"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<cant_productos;i++){
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre de item:    "<<c1[i].nombreitem<<endl;
    cout<<"precio:            "<<c1[i].precio<<endl;
    cout<<"cantidad:          "<<c1[i].cantidad<<endl;

    if(c1[i].dia<=hoy.d && c1[i].mes<=hoy.m && c1[i].year<=hoy.a){
        df=hoy.d-c1[i].dia;
        cout<<"ya vencio"<<"por"<<"dias"<<endl;
    }
    else{
    cout<<"no vencio"<<endl;
    }
}
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿qué error tiene el if que estás haciendo?, ¿tienes algún error en visual studio?, si es así, por favor, [edit] la pregunta para incluir los detalles del error. Creo que serviría también si agregas un ejemplo de qué input "datos" estás metiendo en la aplicación y qué resultados muestra la aplicación.

Comment: Como dice @MauricioAriasOlave es complicado encontrar el error, ya que posiblemente sea un error pequeño y no de gran sintaxis. Lo mejor es que comentes el error que pone el if (la línea al menos) o que uses el debugg mirando las variables locales y seguro que lo sacas. El debugg es una herramienta muy útil si aprendes a utilizarla

Answer (score 2):

**Cuidado con fflush**

`fflush`, de acuerdo con la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/), **no** debe usarse con dispositivos de **entrada**, como sucede, en tu caso, con `stdin`:

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Que viene a decir, más o menos:

> En el resto de casos, el comportamiento es dependiente de la implementación de la librería. En algunas implementaciones, vaciar un *stream* de lectura hace que el mismo se limpie (pero éste no es un comportamiento portable).

Así que yo iría olvidandome de hacer eso de

```
fflush(stdin);
```

No es una práctica aconsejable. Para limpiar el *stream* de entrada en C++ puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::cin.clear(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

Donde `numeric_limits` es una plantilla que puedes encontrar en la librería `limits` y que da información relevante sobre los tipos nativos (`int`, `float`, `double`, ...), como el valor máximo, valor mínimo, etc...

En resumen, lo que hace esta llamada es eliminar todos los caracteres que se encuentren (hasta llegar al valor dado por `numeric_limits`) hasta llegar a un salto de línea, caracter que también será eliminado.

**No mezcles buffers de C con buffers de C++**

Hay gente que primero aprende C y después pasa a C++. De entre este colectivo, un grupo suele participar en retos online que evalúan la rapidez con la que tu programa es capaz de resolver un problema. Este colectivo suele notar que los programas en C++ suelen ser más lentos que si programasen directamente en C y de ahí surge la falsa creencia de que un programa en C va a ser **siempre** más rápido que un programa en C++.

Uno de los motivos principales por el que un programa en C++ acaba siendo más lento que su homólogo en C es porque C++ ha heredado los *streams* de C (`stdin` y `stdout`), entonces, para que éstos funcionen correctamente con las clases propias de C++ (`std::cin` y `std::cout`), la librería de C++ tiene que sincronizar los *streams*, y es facil entender que si una funcionalidad ejecuta más código será más lenta.

¿A qué viene todo esto?

Pues a que este sincronismo se puede deshabilitar facilmente. Podemos ver en la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) que para limitar la sincronización basta con llamar a:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Tras esta llamada, el código que mezcle usos de `stdin` y `cin` tendrán resultados indeterminados. Y, dado que no puedes evitar que alguien incluya esa línea en cualquier parte del programa, mi consejo es que no mezcles las lecturas de C con las de C++ y lo mismo para las escrituras.

**No uses variables globales**

Las variables globales son la causa de múltiples problemas. Su vida es infinita y son accesibles desde cualquier parte del código, por lo que cualquier parte del programa puede modificar su valor sin que te enteres.

Acostúmbrate a usar variables locales y a reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible. Conseguirás evitar muchos dolores de cabeza.

**Si estás en C++, usa C++**

Tu código tiene pocas referencias explícitas a C++. De hecho parece más un programa hecho en C (aunque no llegue a compilar siguiendo las reglas de dicho lenguaje).

C++ dispone, por ejemplo, de la clase `std::string` que viene a sustituir la inmensa mayoría de usos de `char*`. Una de sus principales ventajas es que te despreocupas del tamaño de la cadena a almacenar (eso sin contar con que su uso es más intuitivo).

```
struct tienda{
  std::string nombreitem;
  int  precio;
  int cantidad;
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int year;
  fecha vc;
};
```

Así mismo, para los arrays sería preferible usar `std::array` a `c1[200]`.

**Aislar código repetido / complejo**

Tu programa realiza, por ejemplo, varias comparaciones de fechas... lo lógico sería aislar esa lógica en una función para no tener que repetir código.

En C++, además, existe la sobrecarga de operadores. Esta característica, usada con sentido común, permite que la calidad del código mejore enormemente.

Por ejemplo, para saber si una fecha es *menor* que otra (es decir, si es anterior):

```
bool operator<=(fecha const& f1, fecha const& f2)
{
  if( f1.a < f2.a )
    return true;
  else if( f1.a > f2.a )
    return false;

  if( f1.m < f2.m )
    return true;
  else if( f1.m > f2.m )
    return false;

  return (f1.d <= f2.d);
}
```

¿Y cómo se usa esto? Facil:

```
// Antes
if(c1[i].dia<=hoy.d && c1[i].mes<=hoy.m && c1[i].year<=hoy.a){
    df=hoy.d-c1[i].dia;
    cout<<"ya vencio"<<"por"<<"dias"<<endl;
}

// Despues
if( c1[i] <= hoy ){
    df=hoy.d-c1[i].dia;
    cout<<"ya vencio"<<"por"<<"dias"<<endl;
}
```

Al final se trata de aislar funcionalidad compleja, de tal forma que el código sea más sencillo y legible.

**Calcular dias entre dos fechas**

Hacer este cálculo a mano no es trivial, ya que hay que tener en cuenta varios detalles:

- Si es el mismo mes y el mismo año el cálculo es directo
- Meses de 30 y 31 días
- Años bisiestos (por el tema de que febrero tiene, a veces, 29 días)

Y todo esto teniendo en cuenta que un año es bisiesto si es disible entre 4 pero no entre 100 ... salvo que sí sea divisible entre 400 (quien no sabe ésto).

Así pues, puedes embeber toda esta lógica en una función (lo dejo como ejercicio al lector), o bien puedes hacer uso de funciones que ya existen en el sistema... aunque ello implica adaptar tus datos:

```
std::tm FechaATm(fecha const& fecha)
{
  return {0,0,0,fecha.d,fecha.m-1,fecha.a-1900};
}

int Distancia(fecha const& f1, fecha const& f2)
{
  int toReturn = 0;

  std::tm tm1 = FechaATm(f1);
  std::tm tm2 = FechaATm(f2);
  std::time_t x = std::mktime(&tm1);
  std::time_t y = std::mktime(&tm2);

  if ( x != static_cast<std::time_t>(-1) && y != static_cast<std::time_t>(-1) )
  {
    toReturn = static_cast<int>(std::difftime(y, x)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
  }

  return toReturn;
}

int main()
{
  fecha f1{14,7,2018};
  fecha f2{29,8,2018};

  std::cout << Distancia(f1,f2);
}
```

Comment: Un apunte más que podría ser añadido a tus consejos: los símbolos que empiezan por guion bajo (`_`) están reservados para uso interno del compilador y no deben ser usados por el programador (lo digo por el `_getch()` del final del código de Marco).

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/078sfkak.aspx

Comment: No lo pillo, ya se que la función existe.

Comment: Me refiero a que hay funciones que ya vienen así proporcionadas por las librerías base (no la estándar, ojo), y que están ahí para que las use el programador (tampoco quería extenderme mucho para no ensuciar los comentarios). Es decir, no comenté el tema de empezar por guión bajo porque no se están declarando funciones que infrinjan esa norma sino que se están usando funciones ya declaradas por la librería base... lo cual no debería suponer un problema porque no es lo que limita el estándar (eso sí, no es portable)

Comment: Me suena que aunque la función exista, no se espera que sea usada directamente (Microsoft suele ocultar estas `_funciones` tras un alias para hacer alguna de sus brujerías), pero no encuentro la documentación que valide mi postura.